# What went wrong? All files gone (BTRFS)

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, filesystems, ubuntu-server, btrfs

I am running an Ubuntu server 20.xx.x LTS since 2019 with some drives mounted as a BTRFS raid drive. I have never had any issues.

Earlier this summer I went to another country and didn't need the server so I turned it off for some months. Now I got home, I started it up and everything worked as it should, all docker containers worked etc.

I then did `sudo apt-get update` , `sudo apt-get upgrade` and then I rebooted it with `sudo reboot`. Usually a reboot takes around 2-5 minutes but this time it took around 15 minutes. Slightly odd but there was a lot of updates to be installed since it was turned off for a long time.

After reboot one docker container did not start, a folder is missing from the BTRFS drives. I `cd` to the folder and it is in fact missing. No important, just some config I figure I must have deleted by accident before leaving earlier this summer.

After I create the folder the container starts as normal. Then Nextcloud complains about missing .ocdata. This is weird, I `cd` into the nextcloud data folder and there is nothing. Everything is gone.

It turns out that the BTRFS volume is empty except for a few empty folders.
I have no idea what happened, I have not done anything I have not done before without issues. To protect the server until I have figured out what might have gone wrong I turned it off.

I have a backup of everything but that is a few months old and I really do not want to loose any files. My guess is that something went wrong when mounting the BTRFS drives after the update. Since the server took unusually long time to boot, something went wrong there. I know for sure the files were there right before I rebooted the server.

I have no idea what have happened and I do not know how to correct this issue without risking file loss. How do I proceed with fixing this issue? What have probably gone wrong? What do I do now?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What RAID type have you used? See if [btrfs Restore](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Restore) can help find the data.

Comment: @harrymc I have used RAID 1. I will check that out, thx

Comment: did you manage to access your files @J.Doe ?